# Text Field rendering

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder, xcode4

I am trying to build a really simple `NSTextField` with Interface Builder (XCode 4), but the rendering is really weird with default values:
[image: Current rendering]

The only setting I changed is the border style:
[image]

**My question:**

How to display a neat Text Field “squared but with rounded corners”, like in Safari:
[image: Safari Text Field]

<del>How to remove that “overflow:hidden” (sorry for the CSS description) which cuts the focus?</del> < Interface Builder bug, fixed.

Should I design my own, image-based component?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found *exactly* what you're looking for.  Here's what it looks like:
[image]

It's called **SSTextField**.  Download the subclass here: http://cocoatricks.com/2010/06/a-better-looking-text-field/

Answer (score 3):

What you've got at the top is a `NSSearchField`, which is designed for filtering/searching.

Likely the reason why the focus ring is cut off is because you've got it inside a box or overlapping another object.  Don't do that.

There are no standard rounded-corner (as opposed to rounded-end) text fields; if you want one, you'll need to subclass `NSTextField` yourself, or just wait for Lion where the standard text field will have rounded corners.

Comment: It’s a NSTextField with a rounded corner style (I edited my question). There is no overlapping object, it’s directly on the window. Thanks for the “Lion rounded-corner” advice!

Comment: OK. Well, in that case, don't use that style except for searching.  I don't have Xcode 4 so it may just be a display artifact in IB; try running your app and see if the focus ring is still cut off.

Comment: I believe it's a bug, as I had the same problem myself a while ago.

Comment: Update: It doesn't look like Lion has rounded-corner text fields?

Answer (score 2):

Rounded rectangle text fields are pretty straightforward and don't require subclassing the control. Instead you can simply override the way the background CALayer of the control is drawn.

Choose the square-cornered field shape, add the QuartzCore framework to your project, and then `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`. In your controller's `viewDidLoad` method you'll modify the text field's layer's `cornerRadius` property, a la:

```
myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
```

Poof, rounded-rectangle text field!

Comment: This is on the Mac - layer-backed controls are optional and I don't think they'll do what you want in any case.

Comment: @Nicholas Ah, missed the tags, my mistake. This works exactly as desired with a UITextField in Cocoa Touch.