# Border radius on an NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield, border

Been searching for a solution for the past few hours and so far have been only able to find a way to change the border radius of an NSTextField item on iOS as apposed to Mac. Trying to replicate the design that Safari, Firefox, and other applications have with a subtle round edge along the corners of their text fields.

I am aware that there is an option in interface builder to change NSTextField's to search field thus resulting in a roundness, but the amount that it does it is too severe.

Any help researching the subject or looking for example code on the Mac would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Field rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765572/text-field-rendering)

Comment: (Summary of that response: this is not a standard text field; it will be in Lion, so you can either just wait or make your own.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to create your own custom control.

You can find an great example in Dan Messing's blog which does something similar. Maybe you can modify it to get the style you need.

[Custom Text Field](http://cocoatricks.com/2010/06/a-better-looking-text-field/)